# What's the "right way" to open a websocket connection inside WebGL?

Tags: unity, websocket

The [official Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html) says that, to run websockets in the WebGL player, you should use [this plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/?&_ga=2.35872736.1377041412.1560217376-1923998260.1542458905#!/content/38367e) on the Asset Store.  Unfortunately, following that link leads to a notice that this asset has been deprecated and is no longer available, with no explanation as to why or what should be done to replace it.

With that unavailable, how should I implement WebGL websockets in my game?

Comment: I am not an expert in this, I searched in google and found this two link which I thought might be helpful for you.

1. https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/networking-and-multiplayer/integrating-socketio-with-unity-5-webgl-r4365/

2. https://github.com/jirihybek/unity-websocket-webgl

Comment: Do you need to interface with an existing WebSocket server? If this is a greenfield project, you might want to consider the Unity [UNet](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetOverview.html) system which also works via WebSocket.